# how to add recurring profile and simple product to cart

Tags: magento

i need to add recurring profile and simple product to cart. how can i do this in magento is there any possible to do this 
However, when I go to checkout it says “Nominal item can be purchased standalone only. To proceed please remove other items from the quote.” How do I allow people to subscribe to the service and purchase the products at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, here is the reason why that is stated in the core :

```
/**
 * Temporary workaround for purchase process: it is too dangerous to purchase more than one nominal item
 * or a mixture of nominal and non-nominal items, although technically possible.
 *
 * The problem is that currently it is implemented as sequential submission of nominal items and order, by one click.
 * It makes logically impossible to make the process of the purchase failsafe.
 * Proper solution is to submit items one by one with customer confirmation each time.
 */
```